# Flash is not working on redirection: Rails - 3.2.21

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
flash[:notice] = "message"

redirect_to :root
```

Things which I have tried

```
flash.keep

flash.keep[:notice] = "message"

flash.now[:notice] = "Hello world"

redirect_to :root, :flash => {:notice => "message"}
```

I am using rails 3.2.21 and ruby 1.9.3
Earlier I was using rails 3.2.5 and it was working fine.

If I am rendering flash message on the same page, it is working fine, but for redirect flash is empty

Can some one help me out. I don't want to update ruby version as there are lot of other dependency for my app

Comment: `redirect_to show_path, :flash => { :notice => message}` try this

Comment: I had already tried this. But it is not working. Earlier I was using rails 3.2.5 and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `` instead of "", try this

```
flash[:notice] = "message"
redirect_to root_path
```

Your root view should have `<%= flash[:notice] %>` to show the message!

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But I have used "" only. I will update it

Comment: Did you include `<%= flash[:notice] %>` in the view where you are redirecting?

Comment: I am reading flash.to_json, but flash is empty. Though It was working fine with 3.2.5